OpenPose only selected landmarks
I am trying to use OpenPose but only on the upper extremities. I want the final video only has the skeleton on the hip and above (no ankles and knees).
I tried to remove them from here but it was not the case, any other suggestions for that?
# Defining a dictionary mapping human body parts to their corresponding indices in the model's output
BODY_PARTS = {
    "Nose": 0, "Neck": 1, "RShoulder": 2, "RElbow": 3, "RWrist": 4,
    "LShoulder": 5, "LElbow": 6, "LWrist": 7, "RHip": 8, "RKnee": 9,
    "RAnkle": 10, "LHip": 11, "LKnee": 12, "LAnkle": 13, "REye": 14,
    "LEye": 15, "REar": 16, "LEar": 17, "Background": 18
}

# Defining a list of pairs representing the body parts that should be connected to visualize the pose
POSE_PAIRS = [
    ["Neck", "RShoulder"], ["Neck", "LShoulder"], ["RShoulder", "RElbow"],
    ["RElbow", "RWrist"], ["LShoulder", "LElbow"], ["LElbow", "LWrist"],
    ["Neck", "RHip"], ["RHip", "RKnee"], ["RKnee", "RAnkle"], ["Neck", "LHip"],
    ["LHip", "LKnee"], ["LKnee", "LAnkle"], ["Neck", "Nose"], ["Nose", "REye"],
    ["REye", "REar"], ["Nose", "LEye"], ["LEye", "LEar"]
]```





I am looking for suggetion to make modificantions on OpenPose code to remove skeleton from lower extremities in the vidoe_output.
